# Class to integrate emberjs <-> PHP with JSON data

Tags: php, json, ember.js, ember-data

I am looking something like emberjs-data but for PHP?

Longest description:
I am looking class in PHP to generate JSON for emberjs in standard format and get this data in emberjs. And with other side, i want send data from emberjs to PHP using the same JSON standard.

Comment: Not exatly. emberjs-data generate special format of JSON on server side and emberjs side. In this way i dont care about control JSON data. I am looking something similar to use with PHP.

Comment: It will be good if you can provide a simple example, that way people could understand you better and more chances for getting an answer, cheers!

Comment: What do you mean exactly with `emberjs-data generate special format of JSON on server side and emberjs side`? Can you point out where you've read that? Technically you should be able to use `json_encode`. IMHO it wouldn't make a lot of sense releasing a js library if you need some special library running server-side to simply generate JSON.

Comment: @user1512576 ember-data is not operating on the server, but in the browser. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you are looking for the PHP equivalent of [ActiveModelSerializers](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers/).

Did you looked at http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Serialization?