# How to query JSON file in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I´ve never work with JSON before, but have with xml, php, mysql. I have a populated database on the server and would like to develop a web application with ember.js to interact with this data (CRUD).

Where should I start? I know ember-data has most of the things I would need when developing, but I'm unsure of how to start.

Since the database holds different tables, is it possible to keep this information in one json file? is it the appropriate way to do it? How do I automatically produce this json file from the server?

Comment: Ember-data is the client-side piece you'll need, but you'll need an API (i.e. a server application) to retrieve the data. Is it a SQL database? You can rearrange and interpret the data however you like before serving it through the API in one JSON response. Depending on the database and server-side web framework/technology you will use, it might be difficult or very easy to return the data in JSON format. Can you be more specific about the data and the database?

Comment: @pauldechov It's an SQL database, holding contact info, users, logs, documents, so I would need to query different arrays of data, that's why I asked if I should hold all of the tables in one JSON. But I suspected I would need an API, to hold one array of results at a time.
I'm leaning to use php for the API since I dont work in ROR (which is the server-side common choice when working with ember). Nevertheless, I'm clueless in terms of building the API, so what would you recommend? can you point some examples or tutorials for what I need to achieve?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11538205/90741

Answer (score 0):

you can start with a read query :

You upload a file sample with the json syntaxe on your server (or use your json service if it's enable) to start quickly. Test that you can access to it in your browser, for example :

```
[ {"id": 1, "desc": "hmarchadour"}, {"id": 2, "desc": "moderator"} ]
```

Well now you take/create a view in your embjer js and you can use JQuery to call this file/service :

```
Ember.View.create({
        templateName : "templateName" // you    
        stuff : [],

        didInsertElement : function() { 
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET", 
                url : <url-of-your-sample>,
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(result) {
                    var tmpStuff = json2Stuff(result);
                    this.set('stuff', tmpStuff);
                }, 
                error : ... }
            );
        }
    });
```

Regards,

Comment: How would I combine this with Emberdata? I would use the Router with connectOutlet to throw the results